# how to solve flutter android arm 64 error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to run my flutter app on a real device but it gives me this error

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.

```
 Required by:

     project :app

  > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.

     > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

           > dl.google.com

  > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.

     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

           > jcenter.bintray.com

  > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.

     > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

           > download.flutter.io

  > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.

     > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

           > download.flutter.io

  > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.

     > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

        > Could not GET 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/arm64_v8a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.pom'.

           > download.flutter.io
```

if anybody knows how to fix it please help.

Comment: Most probable cause looks like slow or inconsistent internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> Could not GET 'http://
```

suggests that your internet is not working as expected. Maybe you are using a vpn? In that case, suspend it for a few minutes. If not, it is another internet related issue...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue:

```
$ flutter run
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_sample...                     886ms
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G955F in debug mode...
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-5d8bf811b3072390933d69f3e289a4bb673636c4.
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app                                                   
      > Skipped due to earlier error                                    
      > Skipped due to earlier error                                    
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-5d8bf811b3072390933d69f3e289a4bb673636c4.
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app                                                   
      > Skipped due to earlier error                                    
      > Skipped due to earlier error                                    
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s                                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        97.9s
```

the solution was:

1. Upgrade Gradle `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`
2. Upgrade to dependency `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` in `build.gradle`